# WPF drag rectangle with touch

Tags: wpf, touch, scrollviewer

I have a WPF app with a canvas inside a ScrollViewer. On the canvas I have some rectangles that I drag along a timeline (left-right). This works fine with a mouse, but on a touch screen I get weird behavior if the canvas is wider than the main form. First, when you begin to drag the rectangle, the canvas pans until it has scrolled to the limit, then the rectangle starts to move. I doesn't do this when using a mouse.

Another strange this is that if I pan/drag the canvas (using touch) to the limit of the scrollviewer, the main form compresses by 20-50 pixels on the side opposite of the pan direction. It springs back to shape as soon as you stop dragging. What's going on here and how do I disable this?

It seems that this has to do with ManipulationBoundaryFeedback, but I don't understand exactly how...

**EDIT:**
So I was able to get a little further by setting the scrollviewer panningmode to PanningMode.None in the rectangle TouchDown handler and then setting it back to PanningMode.Both in the TouchUp handler. This solved the problem of the canvas panning to the limit before the rectangle would move.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got my app to work with touch. As I mentioned above, setting the PanningMode to None on the TouchDown event eliminated the problem with the ScrollViewer. Setting it back to Both in the TouchUp event re-enabled it. What this means is that I can't drag the rectangle past the point where the ScrollViewer would start panning, but in my case this was not a problem.

I also had some issues with the MouseLeftButtonDown event firing during the TouchMove event so I removed it during TouchDown

```
-= new MouseButtonEventHandler(drag_start)
```

and re-added it back during TouchUp to eliminate the glitchy behavior.

```
+= new MouseButtonEventHandler(drag_start)
```

Maybe this will help someone in the future...